# How to set up a dynamic prototype chain in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, prototypal-inheritance

In JavaScript I can write a "derived class" whose "base class" is dynamic, with code such as this:

```js
function NewBaseClass(sF) { 
  function DynamicBaseClass(iF) { this.instanceField = iF; }
  // EDIT: oops, this is not really static in the ES6 sense, but it's in the
  //       "base" prototype and, importantly, is NOT in the final object.
  DynamicBaseClass.prototype.staticField = sF;
  return DynamicBaseClass;
}
function NewDerivedClass(baseClass) {
  function DerivedClass(iF, dF) {
    baseClass.call(this, iF);
    this.derivedField = dF;
  }
  DerivedClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(DerivedClass.prototype, 'constructor', { 
    value: DerivedClass,
    enumerable: false, // omit from 'for in' loop
    writable: true
  });
  DerivedClass.prototype.dump = function dump() {
    console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
        " derivedField=" + this.derivedField + 
        " staticField=" + this.staticField + 
        " base=" + this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name);
  }
  return DerivedClass;
}
var BaseClass1 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype #1");
var BaseClass2 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype #2");
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(3, 33).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(4, 44).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(5, 55).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(6, 66).dump();
// Output:
//   instanceField=3 derivedField=33 staticField=dynamic prototype #1 base=DynamicBaseClass
//   instanceField=4 derivedField=44 staticField=dynamic prototype #1 base=DynamicBaseClass
//   instanceField=5 derivedField=55 staticField=dynamic prototype #2 base=DynamicBaseClass
//   instanceField=6 derivedField=66 staticField=dynamic prototype #2 base=DynamicBaseClass
```

(There are various reasons to do this; in my case it saves memory: if a large group of objects all need the same values for several properties, they can efficiently share these common values in the prototype chain.)

How can I achieve a similar effect in TypeScript? It's okay if the code for defining the class is a bit ugly, as long as it is possible to write `new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass))` such that this expression has a reasonable type.

Comment: "if a large group of objects all need the same values for several properties, they can efficiently share these common values in the prototype chain" --- or you could simply pass a map/object as a dependency to them.

Comment: Sure, but storing stuff in a prototype is relatively "free" since it doesn't consume an extra property slot in every object.

Comment: You work with so many objects that the cost of 1 extra property is too high?

Comment: I'm authoring a [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/holders) that requires many small objects, and considering that perhaps at least one of my users (= developers) would create numerous objects and appreciate not wasting memory. Often each object will only have a single unique prop, so storing two props is a significant increase.

Comment: @Qwertie Fair, but be careful about the assumption that the memory is wasted, or that this will be a good way to avoid it. Runtime environments like V8 already have [a lot of optimizations for small, common Javascript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7413168/1426891), and less-idiomatic cleverness might keep you from taking advantage of those automatic optimizations. Besides, depending on your library's use case, you might find you've just traded cheap bytes of RAM for prototype lookup CPU cycles...or not, due to the same optimizations above. I'd profile it before working too hard on it.

Answer (score 1):

### General solution

The following code produces the same effect in TypeScript (`staticField` is on the prototype chain and not on the derived object). Note, however, that using a truly `static` field in the base class is easier: you won't need to write `as BaseClass` in `NewBaseClass`.

- TypeScript 3.8.3 doesn't fully accept it: it complains about `DerivedClass`, saying "A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'". However this error can be be suppressed with `// @ts-ignore`.
- TypeScript 3.6.5 doesn't seem to understand that `baseClass` is non-empty and therefore gives multiple errors. It also says "Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'DerivedClass'" which is weird since `NewDerivedClass` is not exported. A workaround for the latter error is to define a matching interface and use it as the return type:

  ```
  interface DerivedClass_ {
    new (iF: number, dF: number): {
      derivedField: number;
      dump(): void;
    }
  }
  ```

```
interface BaseClass {
  new (iF: number): {
    instanceField: number;
    staticField: string;
  };
}
function NewBaseClass(sF: string): BaseClass {
  class DynamicBaseClass {
    instanceField: number;
    staticField?: string; // a value assigned here wouldn't be on the prototype
    constructor(iF: number) { this.instanceField = iF; }
  }
  DynamicBaseClass.prototype.staticField = sF;
  return DynamicBaseClass as BaseClass;
}
function NewDerivedClass<Base extends BaseClass>(baseClass: Base) {
  // @ts-ignore "A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter..."
  class DerivedClass extends baseClass {
    derivedField: number;
    constructor(iF: number, dF: number) {
      super(iF);
      this.derivedField = dF;
    }
    dump() {
      console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
          " derivedField=" + this.derivedField + 
          " staticField=" + this.staticField +
          " base=" + (this as any).__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name);
    }
  }
  return DerivedClass;
}
var BaseClass1 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype chain #1");
var BaseClass2 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype chain #2");
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(3, 33).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(4, 44).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(5, 55).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(6, 66).dump();
```

The compiler's output looks like this in TS 3.6.3 and works as expected:

```js
"use strict";
var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();
function NewBaseClass(sF) {
    var DynamicBaseClass = /** @class */ (function () {
        function DynamicBaseClass(iF) {
            this.instanceField = iF;
        }
        return DynamicBaseClass;
    }());
    DynamicBaseClass.prototype.staticField = sF;
    return DynamicBaseClass;
}
function NewDerivedClass(baseClass) {
    // @ts-ignore "A mixin class must have a constructor with a single rest parameter of type 'any[]'."
    var DerivedClass = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
        __extends(DerivedClass, _super);
        function DerivedClass(iF, dF) {
            var _this = _super.call(this, iF) || this;
            _this.derivedField = dF;
            return _this;
        }
        DerivedClass.prototype.dump = function () {
            console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
                " derivedField=" + this.derivedField +
                " staticField=" + this.staticField +
                " base=" + this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name);
        };
        return DerivedClass;
    }(baseClass));
    return DerivedClass;
}
var BaseClass1 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype chain #1");
var BaseClass2 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype chain #2");
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(3, 33).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(4, 44).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(5, 55).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(6, 66).dump();
```

I see it uses `Object.setPrototypeOf` which MDN warns us not to use for performance reasons. I hope the TypeScript people know what they are doing!

### Technique for "cheap" data sharing

If the goal is simply to share data among many instances without consuming any memory on individual instances, it can be done much more simply like this:

```
interface DynamicClass_ { // not needed in TypeScript 3.8
  new (iF: number, dF: number): {
    instanceField: number;
    derivedField: number;
  };
}
function NewClass(staticField: string, foo: any): DynamicClass_ {
  class DynamicClass {
    constructor(public instanceField: number, 
                public derivedField: number) { }
    dump() {
      console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
          " derivedField=" + this.derivedField + 
          " staticField=" + staticField + // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
          " foo=" + foo);                 // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    }
  }
  return DynamicClass;
}
```

Notice that `dump()` can reference parameters without storing them in the class anywhere! In general, the JS runtime must create some kind of heap object for class functions like `dump()` to share. Logically, it *cannot* store the parameters (`staticField` etc.) in the instance (`this`), because it is possible to change `this` using code like `new (NewClass(...))(...).dump.bind(otherThis)` - and yet the rebound `dump` will still have access to parameters of `NewClass`.

I'm pretty sure that the objects representing the functions inside `DynamicClass` must be created anew every time `NewClass` is called, because these objects are accessible to JS programs. So any technique that involves returning classes or functions from another function will incur a certain memory cost. Depending on the circumstances, this cost may be smaller or larger than storing data in the class instances.

When using this technique, it can be useful to copy parameters into the prototype for debugging purposes:

```
function NewClass(staticField: string): DynamicClass_ {
  class DynamicClass {
    ...
  }

  let proto: any = DynamicClass.prototype;
  proto.staticField = staticField;

  return DynamicClass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### With ES2015 classes

Because the `extends` keyword can take a variable, you can convert away from functional class constructors and into ES2015-style classes.

```js
function NewBaseClass(sF: string) { 
    return class {
        staticField = sF;
        instanceField: number;

        constructor(iF: number) {
            this.instanceField = iF;
        }
    };
}

interface SuperclassType {
    new(iF: number): {
        instanceField: number;
        staticField: string;
    };
}

function NewDerivedClass(baseClass: SuperclassType) {
    return class extends baseClass {
        derivedField: number;
        constructor(iF: number, dF: number) {
            super(iF);
            this.derivedField = dF;
        }

        dump() {
            console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
                " derivedField=" + this.derivedField + 
                " staticField=" + this.staticField);
        }
    };
}

var BaseClass1 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype #1");
var BaseClass2 = NewBaseClass("dynamic prototype #2");
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(3, 33).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass1))(4, 44).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(5, 55).dump();
new (NewDerivedClass(BaseClass2))(6, 66).dump();
// Output:
//   instanceField=3 derivedField=33 staticField=dynamic prototype #1
//   instanceField=4 derivedField=44 staticField=dynamic prototype #1
//   instanceField=5 derivedField=55 staticField=dynamic prototype #2
//   instanceField=6 derivedField=66 staticField=dynamic prototype #2
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=45&pc=70#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-cnQ-XY+nqSNi8AVjJv6-ve27Pnuk5vjOH63F+uA-kuABsZLwfBwGPjuPAAPQYYgADyIBQPU+HUJh2HGDiqrmD6y7ku+NrrnQyTLD6na5vmhbFsWA6ViRAiGmqlhaJeNGQTat4MYoXo2ix3a9hxpadNxWG8eRRoCb+wlWiiPqAeJTECdJbF9pxCmNjxZGTJRAnwRpzpWdZgZSdmrE9ux-YmUAA)

One hazard of this approach is that you can't accept and amend a generic as part of NewDerivedClass, which prevents you from amending an arbitrary class—due, in part, to the possibility that you'll introduce a name collision. See [issue #4890](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4890).

### With ES2015 `static`

Note that the above doesn't use Typescript's `static`, as you've effectively put the static field on the NewBaseClass's anonymous prototype object rather than on the constructor function itself. This is easily remedied by referring to the base class object in your derivation function, rather than treating it as a raw property.

```js
function NewBaseClass(sF: string) { 
    return class {
        static staticField = sF;  // <-- static
        instanceField: number;

        constructor(iF: number) {
            this.instanceField = iF;
        }
    };
}

interface SuperclassType {
    staticField: string;  // <-- static
    new(iF: number): {
        instanceField: number;
    };
}

function NewDerivedClass(baseClass: SuperclassType) {
    return class extends baseClass {
        derivedField: number;
        constructor(iF: number, dF: number) {
            super(iF);
            this.derivedField = dF;
        }

        dump() {
            console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
                " derivedField=" + this.derivedField + 
                " staticField=" + baseClass.staticField);  // <-- superclass reference
        }
    };
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAOQKYHcBCBDAzqgYQBs9cAKXAMQC5FcoAnGMAcwEpEBvRAKEX8QNUUEAyQQSuXFz4C59bLAh0oimBEoxURACaIAvHUoBuWXP7MFkVJu07aYEAFsARqgamz5iAnoMQ0HAMZDA0iI6u7hycXuYCUAAWMLgAdJaq1ra6BoihpnH8AL5ehabFPMxQ7sDYEKiIAMogAA7uEqQAKgCerTLyqkpZ9ipMrPkCYBghYRFuDGy0MQW5YFZ1Qw7Oc+NFZTw8oJCwCCgYACLuMABuqDrEpGQueISSuLRNrQztUt2t0V5CERiRDfaSoAAeVTAOmkT3w9ykfQKOkuNx0G3CW3cO28vkYASgQWmm0iDAANIh0SS5v9lvIWu5pmwcctEskUiimGihjl0SyBOVljpnM0yLS6fwfKs4ERUCkiHAWGQAETpbCZLS6fTKxAAakQbNSao1dj1sQliB1nOutyG2r1BqSqWt3M1en15olOoUgzd9v1cJepBSPvUQ2ZnsQxTkpR45Su2AYiBw8NeAEYcmgsM8EeRlToumBsE51Ihmgw4ISoD16gBiNPKiMJpMpoNSABMmYwrdzKoLRZLynLlcrNcQtfbjdMk3QiDIWYuXNuvZ76bYbDIAGYKZvN2wOSKxdOMHOF6jl68yKvSGn12QACwU+-3-fCpyiiMz0-nc93S-Xjs7wAVgpICgNfQ9PxPecfyXP8HgA3B2zvAA2CkUJQiD3yPHgAHpcMQAB5EAoGaEjqDwgiLFWDJ1j9TdKV-O1dxUNQND9fti1LYcqzHetKIEY06LsfR70YuC7WfVjfREzjBzLCteN6fj8MEmj1WErUgPEm10T9MDpLDDjCy4odFNHZT2wE6i1hsP0UJ010RIwwz2Nkkz5J4iy63bIA)

### With functional class constructors

This is unlikely to result in very readable code, but it can be done with strong typing (outside of your derived classes) without changing your code. Per related issues [#2299](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2299) and [#2310](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2310), it doesn't seem like there will be a good way to express this safely while using functional syntax. I've kept it using your syntax, and (as recommended in the threads) I redirect the cast via `unknown`.

```js
function NewDerivedClass<T extends BaseClassConstructor>(baseClass: T):
    DerivedClassConstructor<T> {
  function DerivedClass(
      this: InstanceType<BaseClassConstructor> & { derivedField: number },
      iF: number,
      dF: number) {
    baseClass.call(this, iF);
    this.derivedField = dF;
  }
  DerivedClass.prototype = Object.create(baseClass.prototype);
  Object.defineProperty(DerivedClass.prototype, 'constructor', {
    value: DerivedClass,
    enumerable: false, // omit from 'for in' loop
    writable: true
  });
  DerivedClass.prototype.dump = function dump() {
    console.log("instanceField=" + this.instanceField +
      " derivedField=" + this.derivedField +
      " staticField=" + this.staticField +
      " base=" + this.__proto__.__proto__.constructor.name);
  }
  return DerivedClass as unknown as DerivedClassConstructor<T>;
}
```

As you can see in the playground link below, this allows all of the cases you've described in your question, verbatim, and also allows strongly-typed access to `SomeOtherClass.someOtherField`.

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIBtMbYD2IGYUArgmEVMgN4CwAUMsiBAO4AUwAYgC52FALYAjaAEohAeTEArCNWQAyBizZtQZOCCR9gEXABMhIURKgBuDZp1hgCA0dPIyUUAHMryAPS-kGCgiEWQAB2CaMABPMIhbAF8WJOYWGAo9BxJkADkudCw8Am4MQTdyL0l1VkCM6mBsgBFokDgRRwKcfAwMbjAAC2AMIXpkbTBdfUMTMwtoZASAGjGy83EpBmQBoYA6ccmIZxNkAF4VnxS2Ztb2hE6inp2IoijYiB37RyPjU7c+GxqUAgYAoUBAyGubQ6mC6BGQmGQGQA1iAiJxwQj7t1CCR3FQaNZkiwWAhscgAMohCAyAbQB4YapaUgTPSHaauNaWAFsDBUmn9aDfX4ATgADKKAIzc8pwBxOdm-ABEnwQ4UiLzeioBtgQuPI+NovFWcygVVG2wwe2ZByFZ34FyJqWYoEgsEQKEa0GAADcIMZ6cRmZRqLQADy+ABUEbQMPpyAjAQAKsgIAAPSAgYwMrEEQN4kNQAB8jPYXCNs3WUGWxmNlekyDkimUagAktbWYm3qHE8W1EwamxjF7fTX2RWubZB6Iwtx696iMBjNKEgCUmk6llwXlOJ6PCP6d2U+mIJns7HsXn9QXC9wxOeCEJE-Xdz6-QG9cGCd3i-22OlMg04Ivvu2J9IMwzIG2Ogdl2OY9Jen60L2mxDnufrfOO8xLCsmFVsgNa4Wak7IHehTYjsCBwLguBgUMyz8JI0psBaOyoa+o4uL8NbLrYwFvuRzyvHEvyNkoYAUUCsoQLe96PIJGpxIxtiidQrEQDAoAQAACsEcRQDE3B8f6AnqjEcTLAA5LqQYGlAFnLL+mjelRFAQEIRn0osxEnqI0BwGIuBuYEVFYMs-jICEwBgIEwShBZMC0GMIAWcguBEEQYTEZwHgTAFQX6vENQJEpNQeSZLwKe8xjTr8-71Nk1UiDOREDsg1m8oFOxpZ43CKvsrLfCcirIAA1Fs4FWtBUycSNxFsMNbEjoNw1jSxi3oQqs2tfNMpysto3jbsKpCltmiaMNpEQENB0sQA+rd8n3Ts92PbdFEfrZOw3BAJVsJcyBAiCYIQsO-FwgiyKoui8IMmVuYfQW36rsSzDOXQcEYBKvzbhjvXGC0UKqvJZkoAAxBKiolWjMZkQQABM2P5LJvSKvjNyOGqFUk8gpN05TAIcJwyDcNucM9NwGMSpIkjcAAzMssuy5IrHTrOAtcMLoug8ZxSS9L3AACzLAbBvK41zXq0LItcGLvQY3T+sAKzLI7jtm6rJWC5rNva-SEvMw7MsAGzLEHQfu01assNTqa-F71s7r7oH2-rADsyyp6nVNwHQ0RxxrCe29wlIiNStJQPS+sABzLFXVcldEHx8uXtrIFXQep47suisKAKpirkcNwPFso+FMgUGAYQTwILDhWd-XTSYJyy-h2uDYru1fOyJxs4TnNCWTWOXSckK3Bjs8BPP7aL8YJwG6vaEcUvJub-KLg7wTtz75VPNHzCJ+f2hLTHoF8zpJSmmyd+jsH7sUGq7V+g1d5f2Jm8HmDNj6nyAbCEBzA56aAXpApeQcYFLW3mHBB28kEcxQcJXmJF-6YLuMzUBV8IGDVTiQja79M4UPflQomplUF0IwYAphwCMAsPwdfQht8q6cKfrIuRx1t4qm-tzY+Jcy4CgrtiFgQA)

Comment: Under "With ES2015 classes", `NewBaseClass` puts `staticField` in the final instance, instead of in the prototype chain. My answer has a workaround for this, but it's simpler to use `static`. Thanks for that 'functional class constructor' example.

Comment: @Qwertie YW. I'd put `staticField` on the instance because it seemed like the meat of your question was on DerivedBaseClass, and DerivedBaseClass doesn't know or care which prototype contains a `staticField` property slot. Your workaround starts to look like a mix between my 1st and 3rd answers, because you're still convincing Typescript of something that it can't prove is safe. TBH it wasn't quite clear from the description what balance you were looking for across the "idiomatic Typescript", "strong internal typing", and "minimum change" axes, so I tried to pick one of each respectively. :)